# Why VS2010 don't save toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, toolbar

I'm using VS2010 every day, and haven't noticed it before. There is too many toolbars added with third party addons and ms apps.
 Once I revome them by right click - customize everything seems pretty, but every time VS is restarted everything goes back.
 Why VS doesn't save this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, self answer.
First step - check if you ran VS as administrator.
Second step - reset you local setting and try to repeat procedure(again under Administrator rights).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm running VS2010 as administrator and close the toolbars and exit VS. The next time I start VS (as Administrator) it shows all the toolbars again.

I resolved this by closing one toolbar then exiting VS. Then opening VS again and closing one more and closing VS again. Repeat until all the toollbars you want closed are gone. There seems to be a bug in VS2010 SP1 where toolbar changes get lost if more than one change is made.